# Excel - SUM only number 2

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, cell

I want to add all numbers that are only in the SUM-Function in "Number 2".

I wrote all the numbers in one cell which is separated with semicolons ;

But is there an easy function that only adds the "Number 2" and not "Number 1"? So that I can separate it.

Thank you!

I tried to use the SUM function with it, but I don't know how I only mention the "Number 2".

Comment: Maybe you can try this:

Go to Data tab, click on Text to Columns, select "Delimited", uncheck the Tab, check the Semicolon, next, select destination and finish.

Comment: @Vetuka It goes in that direction, but I think I have set the question not completely. It's like that: I have 6 cells which are different categories. I want to add up from all of them only the "Number 2" in one cell.

Comment: So you want to sum the Numbers 2s from 6 different cells? These number 2s are within Texts? Or they are all numbers?

Comment: @Vetuka Yes I want to sum the Number 2s from 6 different cells. The number 2s are in a sum-function. No text or only numbers. It's like that: SUM(1;2;3)

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to understand You problem, because too little info. But try this:

### Solution 1

1. Data is in every cell (1;5;4) (2;7;8) etc.
2. Find first occurrence of semicolon
3. Find second occurrence of semicolon in same cell, beginning from first
4. Get number as text with MID
5. and convert it to number with VALUE
6. Easy part :) sum it.

Only formulas
[image: Excel screenshot with formula]

Only data

[image: Excel only data]

### Solution2

You can transfer data form rows to columns
*copy* data, *Paste Special* with *Transpose*
[image]

and then from Data ribbon *Text to Columns*